# One Input to perform two actions

Tags: html, forms, shopify

I need two things to happen when an input is pressed ( add the product to cart and open an horizontal cart, which is opened by a link Open Horizontal Cart  )

It´s a Shopify Store where I have a product page with a normal "addtocart" inmput :

```
 <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="clearfix product_form" data-money-format="{{ shop.money_format }}" data-shop-currency="{{ shop.currency }}" id="product-form-{{ product.id }}">

      <input type="submit" name="add" value="{{ settings.add_to_cart_text | escape }}" class="action_button add_to_cart"/>

 </form>
```

How can I make this "addtocart" form also open the horizontal cart when the input is pressed?

I´s been a nighmare, sure you can help me out easily.

Thanks

Comment: you can use [shopify ajax](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api), many stores use it.

Comment: How can I do it? docs?

Comment: if you want a cart like this : [link example](http://www.pxclothing.com/), there is a free templates in shopify with that features